# Java CriterialAPI and Date with Milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, jpa, criteria-api

My setup:

```
 - Oracle DB
 - EclipseLink
 - JPA + CriteriaAPI
```

The database has a table with a `DATE` field, called `BEGIN`

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "BEGIN")
private Date begin;
```

Now I try to select data:

```
Date date = getDate();
Predicate p= cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(tab.<Date>get(TAB_.begin), date);
```

the value in the Database is the following
`09.11.17 15:04:41` (Nov, 9th)

the value of `date` is `Thu Nov 09 15:04:41 UTC 2017`

Problem: The query does not return a result, however it should since it is the same date.

I tried this: `new DateTime(date).toString()` which returns `2017-11-09T15:04:41.711Z`

Is the problem due to the `711` milliseconds??? As a short workaround I did this, however it is terribly ugly
`new DateTime(date).minusSeconds(1).toDate()`

Is this a known problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: are millisecs stored in your database for that column ? Oracle normally does for DATETIME, so look at what you have persisted into it. Then look at the SQL used for the query and you have your answer. You could do a BETWEEN query to avoid that

Comment: according to oracle docs: The DATE datatype stores the year (including the century), the month, the day, the hours, the minutes, and the seconds (after midnight).   so no milliseconds

Comment: so what is the issued SQL? and what data is actually stored?